# Translations Don't Apply to All Points

Tags: glsl, webgl

Consider the following vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;
uniform mat4 u_ModelMatrix;
void main() {
    gl_Position = u_ModelMatrix * a_Position;
    gl_PointSize = 3.0;
}
```

In my Javascript program I manipulate the `u_ModelMatrix` to have a rotation and translation. This works on a triangle that I draw. But I noticed that if I draw a second object with its own vertex buffer object:

```
var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, point, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.uniform4f(u_FragColor, 1,1,0,1);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
```

Then the translations and rotations don't apply to this object. I thought it would since `gl_Position` in the GLSL program is the points multiplied by the matrix. This is what I would like to happen, but I'm just curious as to why is this the case?

Comment: Maybe it is for illustration only, but if not, then the fact that the buffer creation and the `drawArrays` call appear together is suspicious, at least. Are you changing the program between the first and the second object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffers get bound to vertex attributes when you call `gl.vertexAttribPointer`. Whatever buffer was bound to `gl.ARRAY_BUFFER` at the time you call `gl.vertexAttribPointer` is now bound to that attribute. Above you're creating a new buffer but since there is no call to `gl.vertexAttribPointer` your attribute is still pointing to whatever buffer you previously attached.

Whether you want to replace the contents of the previous already existing buffer or create a new buffer is up to you.

Comment: Thanks. So what if I wanted to perform a different transformation on the other object?